# Angular 2 show same component with same data in other component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components

Its more design question.

As an example I have a page that display the data, and I have a button that opens up the modal. Need to show exact same page inside the modal, and this modal is an external component.

More detail:
I have a main component, inside which I have another component that receives some data from it via @Input decorator. When I view the page "main-component" it shows all data as expected from message-preview. However I created a separate modal component which is child message-preview component, which is triggered through the button inside . Ho

How can I duplicate (clone) exact same page as in  in modal component without passing data again as its already there?

```
  <main-component>
     <app-message-preview [message]="selectedItem" [context]="context">
     </app-message-preview>
  </main-component>
```

External componenet

```
<modal-component>
        <app-message-preview [message]="selectedItem" [context]="context">
         </app-message-preview>
</modal-component>
```

Comment: Instead of passing it as input, use a service to retrieve `selectedItem` when `app-message-preview` is initialised

Comment: is there are any way without the service, need just to clone same component with same data to a modal..

Comment: Somehow you need to retrieve `selectedItem`, you can either do it through input binding (discarded, because you said there's no direct relationship between `main-component` and `modal-component`) or with a service

Comment: However the modal is the child component of message-preview component. Reflected in question..

Comment: If that's the case, you can pass `selectedItem` as input to `modal-component` as well, and pass it down again to `app-message-preview`

Comment: thanks @bugs going try that..